# I need diagonalizable and non-diagonalizable matrices which are easy to calculate

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking for examples of $3\times 3$ non-diagonal matrices (one diagonalizable and other not). I need some of them which are easy to calculate its eigenvalues, eigenvectors and characteristic polynomial. I need them to use in a class which I don't have so much time to calculate them due to time constraints.

Comment: "I need some of them which are easy to calculate its eigenvalues". You can find those in google-images. You get plenty

Comment: @Moo 3x3, I'm gonna edit my question, thank you

Comment: @imranfat I didn't find it

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=matrices+with+eigenvalues&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX8b-cv9vXAhVBmuAKHdisAg8Q_AUICygC&biw=1280&bih=704  . Getting matrices with "nice" eigenvalues from the internet is not so hard. To diagonalize them is fairly easy.

Comment: Start with easy matrices, then conjugate them by an invertible matrix made up of easy vectors. To get one that is not diagonalizable, use one with non-diagonal Jordan form.